# I can't get my s3 to work with route 53 on amazon web services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have been struggling with this for hours now, I have my s3 bucket named nyxwebsitedesign.com with endpoint http://nyxwebsitedesign.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/

The endpoint works fine but when I go over to my route 53 and under my created hosted zone I created an A record with an alias target pointed to that exact endpoint. I have done this before but this time it is not working no matter what I try, is there a step I forgot? I went through the entire setup guide at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html multiple times now and it still doesn't work.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When I access `http://nyxwebsitedesign.com/`, the website comes up just fine. Is it still an issue?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein when i try to access that it just produces a site cannot be reached dns server not found error, could it be just something I am experiencing?

Comment: SOLVED-- my dns server was the problem.

Comment: @Evan what was the problem with your dns server and what did you do to fix it? I think I'm having the same problem.